# Multidimensional array loop not showing all values in xml api

Tags: php

I am working with uspto patent assignment api. I have just write a sample code to get the result. The result coming in xml format i parsed that xml and i want to display titles using foreach loop but showing only one value.

**index.php**

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('usptodata.xml');
$arr =  simplexml_load_string($data);
foreach($arr->result as $values){
    echo $values->doc->str[6];  
}

?>
```

**usptodata.xml**

```
[result] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [doc] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [str] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 41196-840
                                    [1] => 041196-0840
                                    [2] => 41196
                                    [3] => 840
                                    [4] => N
                                    [5] => 3
                                    [6] => ASSIGNMENT OF ASSIGNORS INTEREST (SEE DOCUMENT FOR DETAILS).
                                    [7] => Y
                                    [8] => 0879-1385PUS2
                                    [9] => BIRCH, STEWART, KOLASCH & BIRCH, LLP
                                    [10] => 8110 GATEHOUSE ROAD, SUITE 100 EAST
                                    [11] => FALLS CHURCH, VA 22042-1248
                                    [12] => METHOD FOR INSERTING MEDICAL INSTRUMENT
                                    [13] => en
                                    [14] => 14046630
                                    [15] => NULL
                                    [16] => Paul CURCILLO
                                    [17] => NULL
                                    [18] => NULL
                                    [19] => 20140100431
                                    [20] => CURCILLO, PAUL
                                    [21] => THE INSTITUTE FOR CANCER RESEARCH D/B/A FOX CHASE CANCER CENTER
                                )                           
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [str] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 41166-549
                                    [1] => 041166-0549
                                    [2] => 41166
                                    [3] => 549
                                    [4] => N
                                    [5] => 2
                                    [6] => CONFIRMATORY LICENSE (SEE DOCUMENT FOR DETAILS).
                                    [7] => Y
                                    [8] => MEMORIAL SLOAN KETTERING CANCER CENTER
                                    [9] => 1275 YORK AVE, BOX 524
                                    [10] => OFFICE OF TECHNOLOGY DEVELOPMENT
                                    [11] => NEW YORK, NY 10065
                                    [12] => KRAS MUTATIONS AND RESISTANCE TO ANTI-EGFR TREATMENT
                                    [13] => en
                                    [14] => 14790492
                                    [15] => NULL
                                    [16] => Federica Di Nicolantonio, David B. Solit, Alberto Bardelli, Salvatore Siena
                                    [17] => NULL
                                    [18] => NULL
                                    [19] => 20160095920
                                    [20] => SLOAN-KETTERING INSTITUTE FOR CANCER RESEARCH
                                    [21] => NATIONAL INSTITUTES OF HEALTH - DIRECTOR DEITR
                                )
                       )
            )
```

In output only single title is coming like this. **"ASSIGNMENT OF ASSIGNORS INTEREST (SEE DOCUMENT FOR DETAILS)."**. How can i get all index[6] titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it should be:

```
$data = file_get_contents('usptodata.xml');
$arr =  simplexml_load_string($data);
// proper variant
foreach($arr->result->doc as $cur_doc){
    echo $cur_doc->str[6] . PHP_EOL;  
}
```

**Explanation**: as you have `result` object, which is a part of `$arr` you need to iterate it's `doc` property, so it is `$arr->result->doc`.

In you initial case: `$arr->result` means "iterate over all subitems of `result`", but `result` has only **one** subitem: `doc`. So your `foreach` takes just `doc` without going deeper and iterating over `doc` subitems.

Comment: What if  `foreach($arr->result->doc as $cur_doc)`?

Comment: Thank you so much now it works can you tell me what mistake i did.

Comment: Updated with a little explanation.

Comment: your answer solved another problems also.Once again thank you.